# Amcharts tooltip - how to manipulate the tooltipText?

Tags: amcharts

I have a chart of dates and i want to add the word "Today" to each tooltip that it's day is the current day, but i'm not sure how to use the {valueY} key since it's a reference....

Suppose i'm creating a function called checkForCurrentDate(), how can i use it in the .tooltipText key?

```
  series.tooltipText = "{dateX}: [b]{valueY}[/] this.checkForCurrentDate(???)";
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/roy_barak/pen/jOQqego)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should call the function when you create the data, like this:

```
chart.data = [{
  "date": new Date(2023, 0, 16),
  "value": 450,
  "value2": 362,
  "value3": 699,
  "isToday": checkForCurrentDate(new Date(2023, 0, 16)),
}]
```

Then, you can use it in your tooltip:

```
series.tooltipText = "{dateX}: [b]{valueY}[/] {isToday}";
```

By passing the result of the checkForCurrentDate function directly when creating the data object, you ensure that the isToday property contains the correct value based on the date.